# Get <td> value on <td> click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have successfully implemented `<table>` `<tr>` click event using **jQuery** in which i get the value of required `<td>` of selected row using following where **.taglib-search-iterator** is my table **class**,

```
$(".taglib-search-iterator tbody").on("click", "tr", function(e){
     alert($(this).find("td").eq().html());});
```

But as per my requirement I need to neglect first `<tr>` row of the **table** and **second last** and **last** column `<td>` of table. So for that I have done the following,

```
    $(".taglib-search-iterator tbody tr:not(:first-child) td:not(:nth-last-child(2))").click(function(){
    alert('Right position clicked');
});
```

Now my problem is I am unable to retrieve the value of `<td>` in 7th column when click event is triggered.

I have done following

```
alert($(this).eq(7).html());
```

But it returns **undefined**.Also i have tried simply using

```
alert($(this).html());
```

And it is returning value of the `<td>` i clicked.

**Question?**

How can i retrieve value of specific `<td>`?

To add, `<td>` ,`<tr>` are auto-generated so it is associated with dynamic **class** and **id** and thus cannot be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.closest(selector)` to get the nearest ancestor matching `selector`

```
alert($(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(7).html());
```